# for-loop not working when prompted

Tags: java, for-loop

My java HW is to play around with some Stock Market data, read/write to files. I'm trying to throw this option (below) into the code and for some reason when I enter `Y`, it doesn't enter the `for-loop`. I can't figure out why. When I enter my `Y` it just goes straight to the next chunk of the code and starts printing data to the screen (as it is supposed to do), without any of the below outputs/inputs.

```
System.out.println("Would you like to add items to the StockMarket data? (Y or N)");
Scanner input_check = new Scanner(System.in);
if(input_check.next() =="Y"){
    //Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name of stock (all caps): ");
    //String input = inp.next();
    names.add(input_check.next());
    System.out.println("Enter date (MM/DD/YEAR) of stock data: ");
    dates.add(input_check.next());
    System.out.println("Enter the opening price: ");
    opening.add(input_check.next());
    System.out.println("Enter the closing price: ");
    closing.add(input_check.next());
    System.out.println("Enter the highest price: ");
    highest.add(input_check.next());
    System.out.println("Enter the lowest price: ");
    lowest.add(input_check.next());
}
```

Comment: Compare `String` values with `String`'s `equals` method, not with the `==` operator.

Comment: I didn't even know about the `String`'s `equal` method, thank you.